# Marble test fails with Jest, but equivalent test succeeds with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs, jasmine-marbles

I'm trying to convert my unit tests from Jasmine to Jest. Some tests started to fail after converting them to Jest. Can someone explain why they fail with Jest.

I managed to isolate the problem to the test case below.

With Jasmine is runs successful:

```
import { JasmineMarble } from './jasmine-marble';
import { cold } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { EMPTY, Observable } from 'rxjs';

class Service {
  foo(): Observable<any> {
    return EMPTY;
  }

  bar(a): Observable<any> {
    return EMPTY;
  }
}

describe('JasmineMarble', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const service = new Service();

    spyOn(service, 'foo').and.returnValue(cold('a|', { a: 'A' }));
    spyOn(service, 'bar').and.returnValue(cold('a-b-c|', { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}));

    const result$ = service.foo().pipe(switchMap(a => service.bar(a)));

    expect(result$).toBeObservable(cold('a-b-c|', { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}));
    expect(service.bar).toHaveBeenCalledWith('A');
  });
});
```

With Jest it fails with this error trace:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  ["A"]
But it was not called.
```

The Jest code:

```
import { JestMarble } from './jest-marble';
import { cold } from 'jest-marbles';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { EMPTY, Observable } from 'rxjs';

class Service {
  foo(): Observable<any> {
    return EMPTY;
  }

  bar(a): Observable<any> {
    return EMPTY;
  }
}

describe('JestMarble', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const service = new Service();

    jest.spyOn(service, 'foo').mockReturnValue(cold('a|', { a: 'A' }));
    jest.spyOn(service, 'bar').mockReturnValue(cold('a-b-c|', { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}));

    const result$ = service.foo().pipe(switchMap(a => service.bar(a)));

    expect(result$).toBeObservable(cold('a-b-c|', { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}));
    expect(service.bar).toHaveBeenCalledWith('A');
  });
});
```

Can somebody explain this behavior?

You can find an example repository here: https://github.com/stijnvn/marbles
The Jasmine example can be run with `ng test jasmine-marbles`. The Jest one with `ng test jest-marbles`.

Comment: As a workaround, I'm now using jasmine-marbles with Jest. Not sure if there are any drawbacks.

Comment: Same for me - after switching from `"jasmine-marbles": "=0.3.1"` to `"jest-marbles": "=2.3.1"`, all tests with spies started to fail :(

Comment: https://github.com/meltedspark/jest-marbles/issues/112

Answer (score 2):

There is now `toSatisfyOnFlush` introduced to deal with this:

```
describe('JestMarble', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const service = new Service();

    jest.spyOn(service, 'foo').mockReturnValue(cold('a|', { a: 'A' }));
    jest.spyOn(service, 'bar').mockReturnValue(cold('a-b-c|', { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}));

    const result$ = service.foo().pipe(switchMap(a => service.bar(a)));

    expect(result$).toBeObservable(cold('a-b-c|', { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}));
    expect(output$).toSatisfyOnFlush(() => {
      expect(service.bar).toHaveBeenCalledWith('A');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Because it happened to me using this solution:
expect(service.bar).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) 
will fail for some reason because its called twice. If you remove the toSatisfyOnFlush block, it never gets called. Rather odd.